# How to configure dns for concourse build container?

Tags: docker, dns, continuous-integration, concourse

Is it possible to configure the dns for the concourse build container.

I know there is a `build_args:` argument with the docker-image-resource but I am unable get it to replicate the following docker build parameter`--dns=IP_ADDRESS...`

Has anyone done something similar in their pipeline.yml?

Comment: Does the DNS of your build need to be different from the DNS of your daemon and other containers on the host?

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely you will be able to set this via Concourse due to lack of support in Docker.

The `--dns=IP_ADDRESS` option you reference is a `docker run` argument.
The `docker build` command doesn't allow you to change the DNS settings for the build containers that run under it.

This [recent github issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/30096) links to a bunch of the related issues:

- [#1916 (comment)](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1916#issuecomment-40007129)
- [#2267](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2267)
- [#3851](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3851)
- [#5779](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/5779)
- [#7966](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7966)
- [#10171](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10171)
- [#10324](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10324)
- [#24928](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/24928)

### Workarounds

#### Set Container DNS for a RUN step

You can modify the local `/etc/resolv.conf` during a build step in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox:latest
RUN set -uex; \
    echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf; \
    cat /etc/resolv.conf; \
    ping -c 4 google.com
RUN cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

It will be back to normal for the next run step though.

#### Set Daemon DNS

You can configure a [Docker daemon with a custom DNS server](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#/daemon-dns-options) for all containers that don't override the dns.

```
dockerd --dns 8.8.8.8
```

It's possible to run a specific "Build" instance of Docker with custom DNS if you needed the builds to be different to what you run your containers run with.

#### Set Host DNS

Edit `/etc/resolv.conf` on the host to point at your DNS. This obviously effects everything running on the host.

It's possible to run a local caching server that can be configured to forward your required requests to a local DNS server and forward anything else to your normal DNS servers (similar to what Docker does locally for a container DNS).